# Code block structure highlighting extension for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, software-development, visual-studio

I'm searching for free tool which paints vertical lines highlighting logical structure of code blocks in Visual Studio 2015.

For example

```
If a = 1 Then
|   If b = 1 Then
|   |   c = 1
|   Else
|   |   c = 2
|   Endif
Else
|   c = 3
EndIf
```

Languages: **C#**, **VB**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension **[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)** has the functionality.

[image]

It is called **Structure Visualizer** and can be found illustrated at [MSDN blog article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudio/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2013) under corresponding paragraph.

It adds 3 things:

- **colorful vertical lines** connecting beginnings and endings of code blocks
- **code structure map** if editor vertical scrollbar is switched to map mode
- **code popups (peek)** at vertical lines leaving the viewport or anywhere on the scrollbar map

Colors can be adjusted in items named "Block Structure" located under Visual Studio menu
**Tools** > **Options...** > item **Environment** > **Fonts and Colors**.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @Caltor - I never used Visual Studio Code so I don't know.